# Did the deaths of Palpatine and Vader make the Jedi more powerful?

Tags: star-wars

Did the deaths of the powerful Dark Side users Darth Sidious and Darth Vader make the surviving Jedi more powerful? EDIT- Did the sudden void on the Dark Side affect the Force Sensitive on the Light Side?

Comment: You mean the *one* surviving Jedi?

Comment: Can you provide any context for this question? Do you mean that the absence of dark-siders makes more force available for the light-side?

Comment: @bitmask technically, two surviving Jedi - Vergere was with the Y.Vong.

Comment: @Kevin: What are you talking about? I never heard of those people. There are exactly three sources of "star wars canon": ANH, ESB and ROTJ as they were originally shown in cinemas. Period.

Comment: @bitmask - Great. Not only do we have [J.K.Rowling](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3500/slytherincess) posting on SFF, we now have George Lucas who travelled from the 1989 as well?

Comment: @DVK: Uhm ... hang on, did you just call me George Lucas? You want your house burnt down? ;)

Comment: @bitmask - #1, I don't live on a moisture farm <g>; #2 I called you a time traveling George Lucas. From BEFORE midi*&^&%^%$^

Comment: @bitmask - technically there were more surviving Jedi (http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18934/what-happened-to-the-surviving-jedi), but most were not around. And by that time, Vergere was more of a fallen Jedi anyway

Comment: I don't know, this sounds very *Highlander*-esque to me...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not in and of itself. The surviving Jedi were few, and only a few of those surviving Order 66 to this point would return to the Jedi path, many remained in obscurity. There is no evidence that the existence of Sith prevented the Jedi from tapping into their full potential - since the Force permeates all of the galaxy, it is not a zero-sum game.

However, the political situation was of course hostile towards Jedi, and force-users had to be wary while under Sidious' rule. Once they were defeated and killed, Jedi could once again begin to practice openly and seek out resources of Jedi wisdom. Palpatine kept a large amount of Sith and Jedi artifacts, and some of these would be recovered for use in Jedi training. Being able to train and learn from previously unavailable resources did enable the Jedi to rebuild their power. In addition, now that they could serve openly, new apprentices could be discovered and trained, thus adding to the Jedi's power.

So yes, their deaths did make the Jedi more powerful by removing a barrier to entry and learning.

Comment: TL;DR: they didn't make any Jedi individually more powerful as Force users, but they made Jedi Order more powerful sociopolitically.

Comment: Exactly. Excellent summary

Answer (score 0):

Well I see the Force as both an energy field and an entity. Roan Shryne, a Jedi who survived Order 66 stated that he felt that some of the Force in the galaxy had run out as he was unable to loose a Force push to help an injured trooper. Sidious was clouding the Jedi's power. Once the Sith were dead, specifically Palpatine, you will notice that the feats of some NJO order Jedi to be higher than Old Republic Jedi. The Sith are gone. Sure you get a few pests like Keuller and Darth Caedus, but yes the Light Side was in an upswing, much better than when Plaugeis tipped the balance in Star Wars: Darth Plaugeis.