# What happened to the Jedi who survived Order 66 during the New Republic Era?

Tags: star-wars

Seeing [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18932/did-the-deaths-of-palpatine-and-vader-make-the-jedi-more-powerful/18933#18933) made me wonder how many of the Jedi who survived Order 66 were still alive after the destruction of the Empire. Some were hunted down and killed by the Emperor's Inquisitors or by Darth Vader, but many simply disappeared or seemed to fade. Except for Aqinos, Empatojayos Brand, T'ra Saa, K'Kruhk, and Ikrit, who joined the New Jedi Order, all the others  seem to have disappeared. Some, of course fell to the dark side, but I can count at least a dozen Jedi [here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Order_66#Known_survivors) that just disappeared. Why did they not reappear later, especially when most of them were relatively young at the time of Order 66 and would only have been late middle-age after the defeat of the empire?

And whatever happened to Rahm Kota?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Legends**:

I don't think canon answers why they each individually didn't appear, BUT:

- Jedi aren't immortal. May be somewhat longer lived, may be somewhat harder to kill. But they can still die, especially in the Galaxy in turmoil.
- The Wikia article covers how **most** of the survivors died, and many if not most did indeed die by the hands of Sith, Vader, Inquisitors, Dark Jedi, Imperials or otherwise died in Dark Times.
- Many probably were depressed over the Jedi Way, seeing how the Jedi Order basically had a MAJOR EPIC FAIL, what with 2 Sith Lords and a bit of help from Gungan comic relief basically having brought all of the Jedi, their precious Republic, and their entire belief system, to a 99.9999% complete destruction.
- Some (4th Wall) simply haven't found an author in SW Universe willing to write about them. There seems to be infinitely many books/comics/games, but there's not actually THAT many to fully trace life histories of every character appearing in other works.

As far as Rahm Kota, bullet #4 seems to have happened. He was (as far as I can tell) alive at the end of the last game where he was a character (Star Wars Battlefront: Elite Squadron) but not (yet?) appeared in subsequent titles.

---

**New Disney canon**:

- As of 2015/02/26, Disney canon isn't known post-order-66+**post-new-Republic** yet - the only Disney canon properties that exist *end at the battle of Endor in Episode VI*.
- Until Episode VII or more new canon works appear, we don't know who and how many survived the Dark years.
- At least one Jedi Padawan survived Order 66 and was fighting the Empire: Kanan Jarrus, born Caleb Dume. His ultimate fate is unknown as far as New Republic era (see above). But since he doesn't appear in the original Trilogy, I'm going to guess he didn't survive till New Republic.
- However, Disney canon **does** offer a plausible theory of why not many Jedi - even if they survived - surfaced during the New Republic era.

  Miller's *New Dawn* book, which is an origin story for Kaleb and sets up the *Star Wars:Rebels*, shows the circumstances under which Caleb fled.

  It indicates that Obi-Wan Kenobi used a Jedi Recall communication device after the fall of the Order (as depicted at the end of Episode III), and warned all the Jedi to hide, and that they were betrayed - **without any details** of what the "betrayal" constitueted.

  In order for Jedi who survived to un-scatter and resuface, they would need to be told that the "betrayal" is over and it's safe, which requires 3 ingredients, one of which is 100% missing, one is almost certainly gone by Endor time, and one is unlikely to be in place:

  1. you need  Obi-Wan Kenobi or Yoda (who are both dead by the time of New Republic), who are the only ones who still knew how Jedi recall beacon worked and that the original order was given.
  2. You need said Jedi Recall Beacon (which is in Jedi Order building, taken over by Palpatine for his Imperial seat, as per *Tarkin* novel, and surely the beacon was destroyed by Endor time)
  3. Moreover, it's never explicitly explained how Jedi listened in to the beacon - but unless it worked 100% by communicating through the Force and didn't require any electronic equipment to recieve the signal, most Jedi survivors would be unlikely to have the recievers anymore years of hiding later.

Comment: Answer 1 I find unlikely - sure, that could explain the occasional one, but not the dozen or so. Answer 2 is not it - these are ones who I specifically said were never said to have died. Answer 3 seems most likely (+1 for Gungan-bashing), along for bits of Answer 4. And I would like to see more on Kota, as the most prominent remaining Jedi master. Good answer

Comment: I think that the Jedi that didn't run and hide *would* end up being killed. The Jedi were trained to help people selflessly for the most part. Being heroic tends to attract attention. The Empire had outlawed all Jedi and placed large bounties on Jedi, so bounty hunters would kill them or even greedy regular citizens. I figure they were either hiding and resisting being heroic or dead. Answer 1.

Comment: Several Jedi simply discarded their lightsabers and began living as normal people. The ones who did that probably wouldn't have returned, anyway - after 20 years they'd be married, have kids, a job, all that jazz.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To Will this answer you gave receive an update in light of recent material that has been released?

Comment: @Boolean - ***"[Not from a Jedi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKF0julgLJ4)..."***

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To ok thanks

Answer (score 2):

Many of the Jedi that survived order 66 decided to simply renounce their powers as well being a Jedi and live in obscurity, anonymity and to never tell of what they were before order 66.

There are several New Jedi Order books that deal with the Jedi that survived the purge and attempted to re-organize themselves into an effective fighting force. Vader encountered one of these Jedi just a couple of weeks after order 66. He fought her and she nearly defeated him. Things that he had been able to do before being cut down by Obi-Wan on Geonosis and being encased in his armor, he could scarcely do. He knew this particular female Jedi and she was only recently granted the title of Jedi Knight. But he could not understand why she was giving him so much trouble during their fight.

Though Vader eventually defeated her.. it was only later when he realized that because of all of the damage to his body, the loss of his legs, the damage to his lungs, eyes, ears, tongue, skin and other trauma, that his connection to the force was greatly reduced, and along with it, his lightsaber skills.

The Skywalker line had twice the potential of Palpatine.. but after Anakins damage, his power decreased to only 80% of that of Palpatine, which was about the same power as Darth Maul had.

Both Vader and Palpatine knew that Vader would never measure up to the potential that he had prior to his horrific injuries. Though Vader did adapt and get most of his lightsaber skill back, his force powers, even as impressive as they still were, were less than half of what they were before his defeat at the hands of Obi-wan.

Of course most of the Jedi were wiped out via order 66. Some became regular merchants, while others became bodyguards, assassins, or simply hid themselves as regular folk, moved to far distant corners of the galaxy and tried to blend in as much as possible and live a normal life away from the empire and prayed that Vader, other dark Jedi or the storm troopers didn't come for them.

Comment: What is you source for this information? I find it interesting but unlikely that he was twice as powerful as Sidious due to the midichlorian counts provided Anakin is listed at 27k and Sidious at 20k.

Comment: It was in a book that came out after Revenge of the Sith. I believe it was called "The Rise of Darth Vader". I did not come across any specific measurement for either Sidious or Anakin's midi Chlorian count.. only that Anakins was "off the chart" But it was mentioned, by Sidious himself in that book, that he had twice the potential of Palpatine and thus like Yoda as well since Palpy and Yoda were a dead even match in their fight.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're left to think about what happens to Rahm Kota. Unless The Force Unleashed 3 comes out, his fate is unknown.

I do know of three Jedi, Ry-Gaul, Solace, and Ferus Olin (a Padawan who left the Order early but later reawakened his powers) were part of The Eleven, a resistance group against the Empire, but Ry-Gaul and Solace were killed and Ferus went into hiding for a long time before being killed by Darth Vader.

The website www.starwarseufanfic.wordpress.com has some great insight on the potential survivals of Mace Windu and Kit Fisto as well as the descendants of Ferus Olin.

Comment: Welcome to this website! A site including "fanfic" in its url is not a very canonical reference... do you have more official informations?

Comment: Everything but the last sentence is a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think something that is being overlooked in this question is where were the Jedi when Order 66 was given?  Of the many un-named Jedi, there were healers and teachers all through the republic that would not be directly involved in the war effort.

Some of the Jedi that survived the initial slaughter would undoubtedly try to regroup with others, but with the large bounty the weaker Jedi would have been taken down quickly.  Smarter Jedi would have had better luck in hiding, running away from the people that knew them.  An I.D. taken from the victim of an accident, a quick Jedi Mind Trick, and the fleeing Jedi can escape into the population or war refugees displaced and looking for new lives and homes.

Also, as Omegacron pointed out, while pretending to be other than Jedi, many would have made new lives for themselves.  Lives that, in rejoining the order as they knew it, would have to be given up.  It seems more likely that Luke Skywalker's success in rebuilding the order would have been aided by the children of those once-Jedi being sent to him with a little home training under their belts.

Comment: These are all good points, but we typically prefer answers that are based in some kind of canon; can you think of any examples from *Legends* materials where any of these occurred?

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is forgetting about Shaak Ti, she survived the stab of General Grevious and retreated to the swamp Plantet of Felucia where she gained control of the locals, then later Darth Vaders aprrentice when out to seek all the remaining jedi and he killed her, so she did live through order 66