# What does Yoda mean when he says, "The Last of the Jedi Will You Be" from the perspective of Legends?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

I ask because as one podcaster put it at that time "you pretty much can find a Jedi by looking under a rock." So in what sense does Yoda mean that since there where other Jedi hanging around?

Comment: Remember - when Lucas and company came up with the line, there effectively *was* no EU. This is one of those times where the old canon levels really came into play: G level trumped everything. The movie said Luke was the last - and the EU decided to not adhere to that statement. The EU is the one that retconned everything.

Comment: @phantom42 What's the retcon?

Comment: All the other Jedi in hiding.

Comment: @phantom42 No, how do they reconcile that with Yoda's line? (Mistake, misinformation, misinterpretation).

Comment: My instinct is that it was a matter of ignorance. Yoda lives on Dagobah because its dark side taint hides him from discovery. It probably also keeps him from noticing that the Jedi are still out there.

Comment: Ah, http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/45172/23243 is one potential answer, i.e. that the Jedi order itself was essentially destroyed. There were light side force users out there, but you couldn't really call them Jedi anymore.

Comment: Thanks Sean though I'm curious to see what what others will find, that's highly plausible even likely explanation.

Comment: Yoda Ghost: So see you, what told you I did true was... from a certain point of view

Answer (score 4):

As per the two opposing answers found in [At the start of A New Hope are Yoda and Obi-Wan really the last remaining Jedi?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21424/at-the-start-of-a-new-hope-are-yoda-and-obi-wan-really-the-last-remaining-jedi/), it's true from a certain point of view. While there were members of the former Jedi Order still alive, still Light Side users, the Order itself was essentially shattered. The council itself had been slaughtered except for Yoda. One way to look at it was that Yoda and Luke themselves were no longer Jedi, merely Light Side users. The other is that Yoda was the sole remaining member of the establishment and therefore the only one left who could grant Luke membership, creating a continuity of leadership.