# Is Luke the last Jedi in the new Star Wars canon?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, luke-skywalker

Is there any proof (or disproof) in new canon about Luke being the only remaining Jedi after the death of Yoda?

I'm aware of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21424/at-the-start-of-a-new-hope-are-yoda-and-obi-wan-really-the-last-remaining-jedi) and I'm aware of lots of Jedi surviving Order 66 in Legends, but I'm looking for a conclusive canon answer. Especially considering the fact that the TV show Rebels introduced characters like Ezra Bridger and Kanan Jarrus.

Comment: As of *when*? You ask if there are other Jedi besides Luke, and then mention other Jedi besides Luke. We also know Luke was training new Jedi at some point.

Comment: Since death of Yoda in ROTJ.

Comment: Timeframe still unclear - immediately after Jedi, Luke is the last Jedi we know of, but sometime in the following 20 years, Luke started training new ones who may or may not all be dead now. Are you meaning to ask *at the time of the end of ROTJ*?

Comment: Let's assume timeframe between death of Yoda and death of Palpatine .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Inconclusive

Because we do not know the fate of Kanan Jarrus (yet) and we do not know if Ezra even becomes a Jedi (much less survives to the point that Yoda dies), we can't say for sure. We also technically don't know the exact fate of Ahsoka Tano yet (see [here](http://io9.gizmodo.com/the-producer-of-star-wars-rebels-answers-your-burning-q-1768048083)).  However, as the events of Star Wars: Rebels proceed, expect this answer to change.

**However, I believe it is likely that Luke was the last Jedi.**

This is a bit speculative, but there are signs in the original trilogy that point to Luke being the *only hope* for the Galaxy. Most importantly, the famous exchange between Ghost-Obi-Wan and Yoda culminating in ["No. There is another"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27358/to-whom-was-yoda-referring-when-he-said-there-is-another). Since the linked question shows that the only other hope was Leia, this suggests that there were no other Jedi who could have been a hope.

Comment: I think you are probably right, although technically you could interpret that as just meaning Kanan or Ezra had no hope of beating the emperor/Vader.

Comment: True. The hope was that due to Luke (& Leia) being Anakin/Vader's children, Anakin/Vader will allow Luke (or Leia) to be close enough, so that Luke can assassinate Vader.

Comment: While the "No. There is another" does seem indicitave of a limited set of options when referring to Jedi, I'm wondering if there is any room to view it as an reformed interpretation of the prophecy that plays such a central role in the prequel series. Basically Anakin was supposed to bring the force into balance according to the prophecy but it appears as if it was his son who was to bring it into balance. And if the son fails, maybe his sibling would fit the prophecy too. I'm not a Star Wars expert so this interpretation may have been conclusively proved incorrect elsewhere in the canon.

Comment: @Jack Yes, which is why I must admit that the second part of my answer is quite speculative as it's based on possibly flawed reasoning. In the end, we simply don't know yet.

Comment: I agree we would have to wait and see what happened with Kanan and Ezra. I somehow suspect they would have to die, otherwise it would be hard to explain whey they didn't train or at least help Luke to learn Jedi tricks of trade .

Answer (score 12):

The crawl of "The Force Awakens" explicitly mentions that Luke Skywalker is "the last Jedi". Since it was a crawl from an "omiscient, trustworthy observer", we can take that at face value.

That said, Pablo Hidalgo in *Rebels Recon* explicitly explained that Jedi & Sith are but two of many "Force-based beliefs" in the GFFA. Some of the other Force-based beliefs/religions are even more ancient that Jedi & Sith.

Kanan & Ezra meeting The Bendu, a being which embodied "the third pole" of the Force, plus some mysterious tweets from Freddie Prinze Jr. (the voice actor of Kanan), hinted that the two Force Users might be finding their own, different path: Neither Jedi nor Sith, but somewhere in the middle.

> He keeps getting closer to the middle.

[(Source)](https://twitter.com/RealFPJr/status/818852757457145857)

Comment: Can't get more canon than the title crawl. Adding the sourced text of the title crawl would seal the deal for this being a correct answer for me. Thanks

Comment: However, the timing of the title crawl in TFA does not meet with the asker's criterion. The OP seems to be asking about after the death of Yoda. While this doesn't *technically* preclude TFA since the new film is, after all, *after* the death of Yoda, the impression that I got from the question is that the OP is asking about immediately after Yoda's death and not sometime later.

Comment: Yes, answer is good, but not definitive . Force Awakens happens much latter, and I'm in fact interested what happened to other Jedi, so only Luke remained. Were they killed, didn't train Padawans for some reason or something else .

Comment: Let's see if I am understanding this: *there is about a 20 year period between Yodas death and the events of TFA where any remaining Jedi (if any) would have to die, as Luke is canonically established as the only one in the new episode. How many Jedi existed in that 20 year period, sans Luke?* It that about what the question shakes out?

Comment: Well, the OP asked "after the death of Yoda"... 20 years later is still "after the death of Yoda" :D ... okay, joking aside, I get your points. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> It's so funny when people started asking that when the title was announced because I never even pondered that question... In my mind its singular. They say in The Force Awakens that he's gone on to find the last Jedi temple. **Luke is the last Jedi**.
>   - *Rian Johnson, director of Episode VIII. [Interview with Good Morning America](https://twitter.com/GMA/status/853004555423973376?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&ref_url=http%3A%2F%2Fheroichollywood.com%2Frian-johnson-says-last-jedi-singular%2F)*

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure my answer is actually relevant and I'm not really aware of what I would call the extended universe lore, but with the translation (in french at least) of Episode VIII's title being [*Les derniers Jedi*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2527336/releaseinfo#akas) which is plural, it seems to me Luke  can't be **the last** Jedi. Together though, Luke and Rey (probably), might be.

Though since Rey hasn't been trained yet Luke is possibly **the last *trained* Jedi**.

Also, being half french I can guarantee it's plural.

Comment: @Edlothiad I added a link to the French wikipedia page and one to the French equivalent of IMDb. Also added that I'm french :) Is that better ?

Comment: @Edlothiad I found the IMDb aka pag and replaced the AlloCiné linked but do edit if you want ! Also I speak a bit of spanish and german and it is plueral in both those languages :)

Comment: Just as a little notice. You may not gain upvotes as your question has quite a bit of speculation in it. Further, the answer above has recently found a quote from the director Stating that Luke is the **last** Jedi, meaning people will take your answer to be mistakes in the translations. However, do stick around and provide your insights into other questions on the site and on the network!

Comment: Don't worry I will ! The feeling of sharing knowledge and learning new things is worth the stay !

Comment: Awesome! We love having new members with new viewpoints, welcome!

Comment: @Edlothiad I have to agree with you. A quote from director is conclusive enough but, those are **a lot** of translation errors. As far as I know, french, spanish, german, italian, portuguese and romanian are definitely plural film names.